# How to find distance of shortest route on graph using dictionary

Tags: python, graph

I need to find the shortest distance from one given node to another using the weights of the edges. I have stored the following graph as a dictionary:
[A visual representation of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaFK0.png)

I've attempted to use recursive methods, but I seem to have failed so far.
Here's the dictionary I am using:

```py
towns = {'kendal':     [['penrith', 28],  ['milnthorpe', 8],  ['barrow', 35]],
         'penrith':    [['kendal', 28]],
         'barrow':     [['kendal', 35],   ['milnthorpe', 31]],
         'milnthorpe': [['kendal', 8],    ['barrow', 31],     ['lancaster', 14]],
         'lancaster':  [['milnthorpe', 14]]
        }
```

The user inputs the start and finish nodes:

```py
places = ['kendal', 'penrith', 'barrow', 'milnthorpe', 'lancaster']

from_town = ''
while from_town not in places:
    from_town = input('Where are you going from?').lower()

to_town = ''
while to_town not in places:
    to_town   = input('Where are you going to?').lower()
```

Then the following code is run, it works easily with nodes directly connected to the start node, otherwise, the recursion continues and does not stop.

```py
routes = []

def get_route(start, finish):
    others = []

    for x in range(len(towns[start])):

        if towns[start][x][0] == finish:
            routes.append(towns[start][x][1])
        else:
            if towns[start][x][0] not in others:
                others.append(towns[start][x][0])

    for y in range(len(others)):
        get_route(others[y], to_town)

get_route(from_town, to_town)
routes.sort()
print(routes[0], 'miles')
```

I am aware that I have no method yet of stopping the recursion, but what I need is for the program to make a list of all the possible routes.

Comment: Why don't you use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) library ?

Comment: @CorentinLimier Sorry,  but I am not aware of this library, and neither is my partner, who I am teaching this to, so I need this to be as simple as possible, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: unrelated - but: why `for x in range(len(towns[start])):` and not `for town,distance in towns[start]:` etc.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks, I'll use that instead

Comment: @PatrickArtner what is ```for town,distance in towns[start]:```actually doing?

Comment: It iterages over the data of your starttown, providing each _inner_ data as `town, distance` - no need to use  `towns[start][x][0]` (which would be simply `town`) or `towns[start][x][1]` (which would by simply `distance`) - look for list decomposition

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems; I recommend that you back up and use incremental programming, so that you can deal with only one at a time.  Start with a few lines of code; debug those before you add more.  For instance, write a routine that checks for a direct route and returns failure otherwise.  Get that working fully before you do any recursion.

For now, your main problem is here:

```
for y in range(len(others)):
    get_route(others[y], to_town)
```

Since your recursion involves no "memory" of where you've been, your recursion performs infinite backtracking and looping.  The only way you get out of this is if `others` is empty for *all* active calls.

I suggest that you look up [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) for help on tracking places you've already visited.

Note also that your function returns nothing.  You have an uninitialized local variable `routes`; this is *not* the same variable as the one in your main program.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - I wouldn't have spotted that. Thank you very much!